# How to setup a domain verification with AWS Certificate Manager for ELB target?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I'd like to create a certificate for an app, that runs on `host.domain.com` address (but I guess the same holds true for `www.domain.com`). The app is going to be load balanced, so I've created DNS `CNAME` record for `host.domain.com` which points to AWS ELB instance. When creating certificate request I've typed in `host.domain.com` as the only domain and in next step I've chosen DNS validation (as it seems most convenient). Important note: I'm not using Route53. Here it gets tricky, because AWS Certificate Manager asks me to create `CNAME` record for `_generatedhash.host.domain.com`.

The problem is that it appears to be impossible. If I just create sub domain, there will be conflict between CNAME and NS records (which cause zone to be rejected with message: `CNAME and other data`). I can't move `CNAME` to sub domain because you can't have `CNAME` at domain apex level (also rejects zone with message: `CNAME and other data`).

How actually can I authenticate address `host.domain.com` with AWS Certificate Manager? Can it be done without Route53?

Comment: It's not impossible. A CNAME record for `_generatedhash.host.domain.com` would only conflict with NS records for `_generatedhash.host.domain.com`. It won't conflict with `host.domain.com` or `domain.com` NS records.

Comment: @ceejayoz maybe i wasn't precise enough. The problem is not with `_generatedhash` conflicting with anything. It is with the fact, that `host.domain.com` is (and must remain for ELB to work) a `CNAME` record. How can you create sub domain `host.domain.com` in such scenario?

Comment: I'm very confused by your question. Setting up a `host.domain.com` `CNAME` record **is** creating a subdomain.

Comment: @ceejayoz Really? I though `CNAME` was just an alias and you need explicit delegation with `NS` records to create sub domain...

Comment: No. `NS` delegation is only needed if you want a *different* set of nameservers to handle the subdomain's records.